# Issue Parsing data to JSON Format

Tags: javascript

I am really new to programming and development world and have a been assigned is to connect to a website API to parse data and create a text file.  The problem I am encountering is the output [object Object]

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='https://api.random.com?key=12346DD-7412-45A6-X4E5-B5D2-45D2983DF12E'; (Dummy Key)
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();

Http.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
        const data = JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
        document.write(data);
    }
}
```

What I get before attempting to parse is the raw data but when I try to just the following code: JSON.parse(Http.responseText).  I get the following output

[object Object].

Comment: `data` is an object, and when it gets converted to a string automatically it will just display [object Object]. You should use the responseText that you already have.

Answer (score 3):

The `document.write()` function takes parameters of type string. `JSON.parse()` converts the JSON string to the object format which `document.write()` cannot understand. So it prints the `typeOf(data)` insted. The result of `typeOf(data)` is a string which is `[Object object]` so `[Object object]` is printed.

Use `document.write(JSON.stringify(data));`

You can refer the docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) which states that it takes in parameters of string type.